# How to create php file can be executed without using comman php foo.php, or ./foo.php

Tags: php

I wondering how to create a php script can be execute without using the php command,
I see on laravel when we want to execute the artisan file, we only write `artisan <args>` on the terminal, is that possible to create something similar like that?

Comment: Take a look at [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll use the Symfony console as an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

use App\Kernel;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;
use Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv;
use Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Debug;

if (!in_array(PHP_SAPI, ['cli', 'phpdbg', 'embed'], true)) {
    echo 'Warning: The console should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the '.PHP_SAPI.' SAPI'.PHP_EOL;
}

set_time_limit(0);

require dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload.php';
/// ... more code here
```

The `#!/usr/bin/env php` sets the interpreter. Which is what the comments above were mentioning.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

echo "I'm PHP Code\n";
```

Running the command

```
./phpCommand
I'm PHP Code
```